# Does it makes sense to use sqlInterpolate on individual components of a query string?

Tags: sql, r, shiny

TLDR: Does `sqlInterpolate` from `DBI` package have to know the entire sql query to properly sanitize user input?

I am using `DBI` package to make queries within a shiny app. Since the app allows free text inputs I need to sanitize my inputs. The app ultimately creates queries like this

```
# representative code
query = "SELECT distinct oneColumn, anotherColumn where field1 in ('userInput1','userInput2'...'userInputN') ..."
```

There can be an arbitrary number of fields and an arbitrary number of user inputs for each of the queries. Based on [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html) tutorial it seems like I need to use `sqlInterpolate` to sanitize user input. Yet it seems that the function only sanitizes individual strings. So in order to use the function as instructed I'd have to construct the query as

```
sql = "Select distinct oneColumn, anotherColumn where field1=?input1 OR field1=?input2"
```

then do

```
sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, input1 = userInput1, input2 = userInput2)
```

Since the number of fields and inputs are arbitrary, only way for me to do this seems like using `eval` which is way worse as now instead of sql injections I am now vulnerable to R injections. To combat this I wish to use `sqlInterpolate` on individual user inputs and concatenate them. Like

```
query = userInputVector %>% apply(function(x){
    sqlInterpolate(conn, '?input',input = x)
})
paste0("('",paste(query,collapse = "','"),"')")
```

My question is if this approach makes sense or not. Can `sqlInterpolate` function without knowing what the rest of the query is? Will I be open to attacks if I simply concatenate the results of the code above